# apache mod proxy_wstunnel invalid utf8 during websocket upgrade

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-proxy, tomcat7, socket

I am experiencing an intermittent problem when connecting the jetty web-socket client to the server. The good people at Jetty assure me it is not a problem with Jetty.

On the server side I have apache with mod proxy_wstunnel proxying to tomcat 7.

When I take apache out of the picture and connect the client directly to tomcat, the error seems to disappear. Also the error does not seem to happen when I run the client on linux, the problem only seems to occur on windows 7.

I've noticed that apache is returning a 500 html page at some stage, however, even if I set the loglevel to debug, I don't get any useful information on how to resolve the error.

If anyone could help me figure out how to resolve this it would be much appreciated. Hours of googling have not helped.

The software versions are:

apache Server version: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu), Server built:   Jul 22 2014 14:36:38
tomcat Apache Tomcat/7.0.52 (Ubuntu) 1.8.0_25-b17 Oracle Corporation Linux
   3.13.0-32-generic 
Jetty client: 9.2.6.v20141205

The apache wstunnel config:

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>

            ServerName ws.redacted.io

            ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

            ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
            CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

            <Directory />
                    AllowOverride none
                    Require all denied
            </Directory>
        LogLevel debug
            ProxyPass /redacted-srv/ ws://localhost:8080/redacted-srv/
            ProxyPassReverse /redacted-srv/ ws://localhost:8080/redacted-srv/

    </VirtualHost>
```

The apache error log:

```
    [Mon Dec 29 13:33:21.355169 2014] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 1074:tid 140252728342400] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
    [Mon Dec 29 13:33:22.141202 2014] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 9328:tid 140463177648000] AH00489: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) mod_jk/1.2.37 configured -- resuming normal operations
    [Mon Dec 29 13:33:22.141279 2014] [core:notice] [pid 9328:tid 140463177648000] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
    [Mon Dec 29 13:33:22.141935 2014] [proxy:debug] [pid 9331:tid 140463177648000] proxy_util.c(1694): AH00925: initializing worker ws://localhost:8080/redacted-srv/ shared
    [Mon Dec 29 13:33:22.141977 2014] [proxy:debug] [pid 9331:tid 140463177648000] proxy_util.c(1734): AH00927: initializing worker ws://localhost:8080/redacted-srv/ local
    [Mon Dec 29 13:33:22.141993 2014] [proxy:debug] [pid 9331:tid 140463177648000] proxy_util.c(1769): AH00930: initialized pool in child 9331 for (localhost) min=0 max=25 smax=25
    [Mon Dec 29 13:33:22.142526 2014] [proxy:debug] [pid 9330:tid 140463177648000] proxy_util.c(1694): AH00925: initializing worker ws://localhost:8080/redacted-srv/ shared
    [Mon Dec 29 13:33:22.142574 2014] [proxy:debug] [pid 9330:tid 140463177648000] proxy_util.c(1734): AH00927: initializing worker ws://localhost:8080/redacted-srv/ local
    [Mon Dec 29 13:33:22.142595 2014] [proxy:debug] [pid 9330:tid 140463177648000] proxy_util.c(1769): AH00930: initialized pool in child 9330 for (localhost) min=0 max=25 smax=25
    [Mon Dec 29 13:33:33.367328 2014] [authz_core:debug] [pid 9331:tid 140463053694720] mod_authz_core.c(828): [client 105.210.40.30:50872] AH01628: authorization result: granted (no directives)
    [Mon Dec 29 13:33:33.367463 2014] [proxy:debug] [pid 9331:tid 140463053694720] mod_proxy.c(1104): [client 105.210.40.30:50872] AH01143: Running scheme ws handler (attempt 0)
    [Mon Dec 29 13:33:33.367483 2014] [proxy_http:debug] [pid 9331:tid 140463053694720] mod_proxy_http.c(1892): [client 105.210.40.30:50872] AH01113: HTTP: declining URL ws://localhost:8080/redacted-srv/ws
    [Mon Dec 29 13:33:33.367493 2014] [proxy_wstunnel:debug] [pid 9331:tid 140463053694720] mod_proxy_wstunnel.c(331): [client 105.210.40.30:50872] AH02451: serving URL ws://localhost:8080/redacted-srv/ws
    [Mon Dec 29 13:33:33.367517 2014] [proxy:debug] [pid 9331:tid 140463053694720] proxy_util.c(2020): AH00942: WS: has acquired connection for (localhost)
    [Mon Dec 29 13:33:33.367526 2014] [proxy:debug] [pid 9331:tid 140463053694720] proxy_util.c(2072): [client 105.210.40.30:50872] AH00944: connecting ws://localhost:8080/redacted-srv/ws to localhost:8080
    [Mon Dec 29 13:33:33.367767 2014] [proxy:debug] [pid 9331:tid 140463053694720] proxy_util.c(2206): [client 105.210.40.30:50872] AH00947: connected /redacted-srv/ws to localhost:8080
    [Mon Dec 29 13:33:33.367913 2014] [proxy:debug] [pid 9331:tid 140463053694720] proxy_util.c(2610): AH00962: WS: connection complete to 127.0.0.1:8080 (localhost)
    [Mon Dec 29 13:33:33.384725 2014] [proxy_wstunnel:debug] [pid 9331:tid 140463053694720] mod_proxy_wstunnel.c(253): [client 105.210.40.30:50872] AH02445: woke from poll(), i=1
    [Mon Dec 29 13:33:33.384776 2014] [proxy_wstunnel:debug] [pid 9331:tid 140463053694720] mod_proxy_wstunnel.c(262): [client 105.210.40.30:50872] AH02446: sock was readable
    [Mon Dec 29 13:33:33.811469 2014] [proxy_wstunnel:debug] [pid 9331:tid 140463053694720] mod_proxy_wstunnel.c(253): [client 105.210.40.30:50872] AH02445: woke from poll(), i=1
    [Mon Dec 29 13:33:33.811558 2014] [proxy_wstunnel:debug] [pid 9331:tid 140463053694720] mod_proxy_wstunnel.c(278): [client 105.210.40.30:50872] AH02448: client was readable
    [Mon Dec 29 13:33:33.858796 2014] [proxy_wstunnel:debug] [pid 9331:tid 140463053694720] mod_proxy_wstunnel.c(253): [client 105.210.40.30:50872] AH02445: woke from poll(), i=1
    [Mon Dec 29 13:33:33.858827 2014] [proxy_wstunnel:debug] [pid 9331:tid 140463053694720] mod_proxy_wstunnel.c(262): [client 105.210.40.30:50872] AH02446: sock was readable
    [Mon Dec 29 13:33:33.860386 2014] [proxy_wstunnel:debug] [pid 9331:tid 140463053694720] mod_proxy_wstunnel.c(253): [client 105.210.40.30:50872] AH02445: woke from poll(), i=1
    [Mon Dec 29 13:33:33.860400 2014] [proxy_wstunnel:debug] [pid 9331:tid 140463053694720] mod_proxy_wstunnel.c(262): [client 105.210.40.30:50872] AH02446: sock was readable
    [Mon Dec 29 13:34:02.718967 2014] [proxy_wstunnel:debug] [pid 9331:tid 140463053694720] mod_proxy_wstunnel.c(253): [client 105.210.40.30:50872] AH02445: woke from poll(), i=1
    [Mon Dec 29 13:34:02.719083 2014] [proxy_wstunnel:debug] [pid 9331:tid 140463053694720] mod_proxy_wstunnel.c(278): [client 105.210.40.30:50872] AH02448: client was readable
    [Mon Dec 29 13:34:02.719152 2014] [proxy:debug] [pid 9331:tid 140463053694720] proxy_util.c(2035): AH00943: WS: has released connection for (localhost)
    [Mon Dec 29 13:34:10.503173 2014] [authz_core:debug] [pid 9330:tid 140463078872832] mod_authz_core.c(828): [client 105.210.40.30:50890] AH01628: authorization result: granted (no directives)
    [Mon Dec 29 13:34:10.503299 2014] [proxy:debug] [pid 9330:tid 140463078872832] mod_proxy.c(1104): [client 105.210.40.30:50890] AH01143: Running scheme ws handler (attempt 0)
    [Mon Dec 29 13:34:10.503313 2014] [proxy_http:debug] [pid 9330:tid 140463078872832] mod_proxy_http.c(1892): [client 105.210.40.30:50890] AH01113: HTTP: declining URL ws://localhost:8080/redacted-srv/ws
    [Mon Dec 29 13:34:10.503329 2014] [proxy_wstunnel:debug] [pid 9330:tid 140463078872832] mod_proxy_wstunnel.c(331): [client 105.210.40.30:50890] AH02451: serving URL ws://localhost:8080/redacted-srv/ws
    [Mon Dec 29 13:34:10.503349 2014] [proxy:debug] [pid 9330:tid 140463078872832] proxy_util.c(2020): AH00942: WS: has acquired connection for (localhost)
    [Mon Dec 29 13:34:10.503357 2014] [proxy:debug] [pid 9330:tid 140463078872832] proxy_util.c(2072): [client 105.210.40.30:50890] AH00944: connecting ws://localhost:8080/redacted-srv/ws to localhost:8080
    [Mon Dec 29 13:34:10.503618 2014] [proxy:debug] [pid 9330:tid 140463078872832] proxy_util.c(2206): [client 105.210.40.30:50890] AH00947: connected /redacted-srv/ws to localhost:8080
    [Mon Dec 29 13:34:10.503781 2014] [proxy:debug] [pid 9330:tid 140463078872832] proxy_util.c(2610): AH00962: WS: connection complete to 127.0.0.1:8080 (localhost)
    [Mon Dec 29 13:34:10.507443 2014] [proxy_wstunnel:debug] [pid 9330:tid 140463078872832] mod_proxy_wstunnel.c(253): [client 105.210.40.30:50890] AH02445: woke from poll(), i=1
    [Mon Dec 29 13:34:10.507463 2014] [proxy_wstunnel:debug] [pid 9330:tid 140463078872832] mod_proxy_wstunnel.c(262): [client 105.210.40.30:50890] AH02446: sock was readable
    [Mon Dec 29 13:34:10.967619 2014] [proxy_wstunnel:debug] [pid 9330:tid 140463078872832] mod_proxy_wstunnel.c(253): [client 105.210.40.30:50890] AH02445: woke from poll(), i=1
    [Mon Dec 29 13:34:10.967682 2014] [proxy_wstunnel:debug] [pid 9330:tid 140463078872832] mod_proxy_wstunnel.c(278): [client 105.210.40.30:50890] AH02448: client was readable
    [Mon Dec 29 13:34:10.993060 2014] [proxy_wstunnel:debug] [pid 9330:tid 140463078872832] mod_proxy_wstunnel.c(253): [client 105.210.40.30:50890] AH02445: woke from poll(), i=1
    [Mon Dec 29 13:34:10.993093 2014] [proxy_wstunnel:debug] [pid 9330:tid 140463078872832] mod_proxy_wstunnel.c(262): [client 105.210.40.30:50890] AH02446: sock was readable
    [Mon Dec 29 13:34:10.996379 2014] [proxy_wstunnel:debug] [pid 9330:tid 140463078872832] mod_proxy_wstunnel.c(253): [client 105.210.40.30:50890] AH02445: woke from poll(), i=1
    [Mon Dec 29 13:34:10.996421 2014] [proxy_wstunnel:debug] [pid 9330:tid 140463078872832] mod_proxy_wstunnel.c(262): [client 105.210.40.30:50890] AH02446: sock was readable
    [Mon Dec 29 13:34:39.916202 2014] [proxy_wstunnel:debug] [pid 9330:tid 140463078872832] mod_proxy_wstunnel.c(253): [client 105.210.40.30:50890] AH02445: woke from poll(), i=1
    [Mon Dec 29 13:34:39.916286 2014] [proxy_wstunnel:debug] [pid 9330:tid 140463078872832] mod_proxy_wstunnel.c(278): [client 105.210.40.30:50890] AH02448: client was readable
    [Mon Dec 29 13:34:39.916378 2014] [proxy:debug] [pid 9330:tid 140463078872832] proxy_util.c(2035): AH00943: WS: has released connection for (localhost)
    [Mon Dec 29 13:34:45.982784 2014] [authz_core:debug] [pid 9331:tid 140463062087424] mod_authz_core.c(828): [client 105.210.40.30:50911] AH01628: authorization result: granted (no directives)
    [Mon Dec 29 13:34:45.982890 2014] [proxy:debug] [pid 9331:tid 140463062087424] mod_proxy.c(1104): [client 105.210.40.30:50911] AH01143: Running scheme ws handler (attempt 0)
    [Mon Dec 29 13:34:45.982900 2014] [proxy_http:debug] [pid 9331:tid 140463062087424] mod_proxy_http.c(1892): [client 105.210.40.30:50911] AH01113: HTTP: declining URL ws://localhost:8080/redacted-srv/ws
    [Mon Dec 29 13:34:45.982907 2014] [proxy_wstunnel:debug] [pid 9331:tid 140463062087424] mod_proxy_wstunnel.c(331): [client 105.210.40.30:50911] AH02451: serving URL ws://localhost:8080/redacted-srv/ws
    [Mon Dec 29 13:34:45.982927 2014] [proxy:debug] [pid 9331:tid 140463062087424] proxy_util.c(2020): AH00942: WS: has acquired connection for (localhost)
    [Mon Dec 29 13:34:45.982947 2014] [proxy:debug] [pid 9331:tid 140463062087424] proxy_util.c(2072): [client 105.210.40.30:50911] AH00944: connecting ws://localhost:8080/redacted-srv/ws to localhost:8080
    [Mon Dec 29 13:34:45.982957 2014] [proxy:debug] [pid 9331:tid 140463062087424] proxy_util.c(2206): [client 105.210.40.30:50911] AH00947: connected /redacted-srv/ws to localhost:8080
    [Mon Dec 29 13:34:45.983079 2014] [proxy_wstunnel:debug] [pid 9331:tid 140463062087424] mod_proxy_wstunnel.c(253): [client 105.210.40.30:50911] AH02445: woke from poll(), i=1
    [Mon Dec 29 13:34:45.983090 2014] [proxy_wstunnel:debug] [pid 9331:tid 140463062087424] mod_proxy_wstunnel.c(262): [client 105.210.40.30:50911] AH02446: sock was readable
    [Mon Dec 29 13:34:45.983171 2014] [proxy:debug] [pid 9331:tid 140463062087424] proxy_util.c(2035): AH00943: WS: has

 released connection for (localhost)
```

The ngrep output on port 80 (between apache and the websocket client)

`filter: (ip or ip6) and ( port 80 )
    #
    T 105.210.y.y:49975 -> 104.131.x.x:80 [S]
    #
    T 104.131.x.x:80 -> 105.210.y.y:49975 [AS]
    #
    T 105.210.y.y:49975 -> 104.131.x.x:80 [A]
      00 00 00 00 00 00                                     ......

    #
    T 105.210.y.y:49975 -> 104.131.x.x:80 [AP]
      47 45 54 20 2f 74 72 61    6e 73 6c 61 74 6f 72 2d    GET /trandomain-
      73 72 76 2f 77 73 20 48    54 54 50 2f 31 2e 31 0d    srv/ws HTTP/1.1.
      0a 48 6f 73 74 3a 20 77    73 2e 73 6c 61 74 6f 72    .Host: ws.domain
      2e 69 6f 0d 0a 55 70 67    72 61 64 65 3a 20 77 65    .io..Upgrade: we
      62 73 6f 63 6b 65 74 0d    0a 43 6f 6e 6e 65 63 74    bsocket..Connect
      69 6f 6e 3a 20 55 70 67    72 61 64 65 0d 0a 53 65    ion: Upgrade..Se
      63 2d 57 65 62 53 6f 63    6b 65 74 2d 4b 65 79 3a    c-WebSocket-Key:
      20 56 50 54 4a 79 42 6b    30 36 38 65 7a 66 30 62     VPTJyBk068ezf0b
      34 57 66 41 39 73 51 3d    3d 0d 0a 53 65 63 2d 57    4WfA9sQ==..Sec-W
      65 62 53 6f 63 6b 65 74    2d 56 65 72 73 69 6f 6e    ebSocket-Version
      3a 20 31 33 0d 0a 50 72    61 67 6d 61 3a 20 6e 6f    : 13..Pragma: no
      2d 63 61 63 68 65 0d 0a    43 61 63 68 65 2d 43 6f    -cache..Cache-Co
      6e 74 72 6f 6c 3a 20 6e    6f 2d 63 61 63 68 65 0d    ntrol: no-cache.
      0a 0d 0a                                              ...

    #
    T 104.131.x.x:80 -> 105.210.y.y:49975 [A]
    #
    T 104.131.x.x:80 -> 105.210.y.y:49975 [AP]
      48 54 54 50 2f 31 2e 31    20 31 30 31 20 53 77 69    HTTP/1.1 101 Swi
      74 63 68 69 6e 67 20 50    72 6f 74 6f 63 6f 6c 73    tching Protocols
      0d 0a 53 65 72 76 65 72    3a 20 41 70 61 63 68 65    ..Server: Apache
      2d 43 6f 79 6f 74 65 2f    31 2e 31 0d 0a 55 70 67    -Coyote/1.1..Upg
      72 61 64 65 3a 20 77 65    62 73 6f 63 6b 65 74 0d    rade: websocket.
      0a 43 6f 6e 6e 65 63 74    69 6f 6e 3a 20 75 70 67    .Connection: upg
      72 61 64 65 0d 0a 53 65    63 2d 57 65 62 53 6f 63    rade..Sec-WebSoc
      6b 65 74 2d 41 63 63 65    70 74 3a 20 31 4a 51 76    ket-Accept: 1JQv
      41 2f 43 56 55 5a 38 59    6d 4d 4a 38 70 62 33 53    A/CVUZ8YmMJ8pb3S
      48 33 51 47 56 4e 34 3d    0d 0a 44 61 74 65 3a 20    H3QGVN4=..Date: 
      57 65 64 2c 20 32 34 20    44 65 63 20 32 30 31 34    Wed, 24 Dec 2014
      20 31 34 3a 33 31 3a 31    37 20 47 4d 54 0d 0a 0d     14:31:17 GMT...
      0a                                                    .

    #
    T 105.210.y.y:49975 -> 104.131.x.x:80 [AP]
      82 9c ea 9e d0 54 e2 9e    c3 1e eb af c4 47 a0 98    .....T.......G..
      a4 31 99 ea e1 61 fe 8d    9a 53 9e fb a3 20 db ac    .1...a...S... ..
      e3 40                                                 .@

    #
    T 104.131.x.x:80 -> 105.210.y.y:49975 [A]
    #
    T 104.131.x.x:80 -> 105.210.y.y:49975 [AP]
      82 09                                                 ..

    #
    T 104.131.x.x:80 -> 105.210.y.y:49975 [AP]
      08 00 13 4a 03 32 37 30    14                         ...J.270.

    #
    T 105.210.y.y:49975 -> 104.131.x.x:80 [A]
      00 00 00 00 00 00                                     ......

    #
    T 105.210.y.y:49975 -> 104.131.x.x:80 [AP]
      88 8a bc 23 03 08 bf ca    50 60 c9 57 67 67 cb 4d    ...#....P.Wgg.M
    #
    T 104.131.x.x:80 -> 105.210.y.y:49975 [A]
    #
    T 105.210.y.y:49975 -> 104.131.x.x:80 [AF]
      00 00 00 00 00 00                                     ......

    #
    T 104.131.x.x:80 -> 105.210.y.y:49975 [AF]
    #
    T 105.210.y.y:49975 -> 104.131.x.x:80 [AFP]
      88 8a bc 23 03 08 bf ca    50 60 c9 57 67 67 cb 4d    ...#....P.Wgg.M
    #
    T 104.131.x.x:80 -> 105.210.y.y:49975 [A]
    #
    T 105.210.y.y:49975 -> 104.131.x.x:80 [AFP]
      88 8a bc 23 03 08 bf ca    50 60 c9 57 67 67 cb 4d    ...#....P.Wgg.M
    #
    T 104.131.x.x:80 -> 105.210.y.y:49975 [A]
    #
    T 104.131.x.x:80 -> 105.210.y.y:49975 [AF]
    #
    T 105.210.y.y:49975 -> 104.131.x.x:80 [AFP]
      88 8a bc 23 03 08 bf ca    50 60 c9 57 67 67 cb 4d    ...#....P.Wgg.M
    #
    T 104.131.x.x:80 -> 105.210.y.y:49975 [A]
    #
    T 104.131.x.x:80 -> 105.210.y.y:49975 [AF]
    #
    T 105.210.y.y:49983 -> 104.131.x.x:80 [S]
    #
    T 104.131.x.x:80 -> 105.210.y.y:49983 [AS]
    #
    T 105.210.y.y:49983 -> 104.131.x.x:80 [A]
      00 00 00 00 00 00                                     ......

    #
    T 105.210.y.y:49983 -> 104.131.x.x:80 [AP]
      47 45 54 20 2f 74 72 61    6e 73 6c 61 74 6f 72 2d    GET /trandomain-
      73 72 76 2f 77 73 20 48    54 54 50 2f 31 2e 31 0d    srv/ws HTTP/1.1.
      0a 48 6f 73 74 3a 20 77    73 2e 73 6c 61 74 6f 72    .Host: ws.domain
      2e 69 6f 0d 0a 55 70 67    72 61 64 65 3a 20 77 65    .io..Upgrade: we
      62 73 6f 63 6b 65 74 0d    0a 43 6f 6e 6e 65 63 74    bsocket..Connect
      69 6f 6e 3a 20 55 70 67    72 61 64 65 0d 0a 53 65    ion: Upgrade..Se
      63 2d 57 65 62 53 6f 63    6b 65 74 2d 4b 65 79 3a    c-WebSocket-Key:
      20 53 35 65 55 79 36 78    6a 55 53 70 51 46 57 47     S5eUy6xjUSpQFWG
      37 2b 4a 4d 66 2b 51 3d    3d 0d 0a 53 65 63 2d 57    7+JMf+Q==..Sec-W
      65 62 53 6f 63 6b 65 74    2d 56 65 72 73 69 6f 6e    ebSocket-Version
      3a 20 31 33 0d 0a 50 72    61 67 6d 61 3a 20 6e 6f    : 13..Pragma: no
      2d 63 61 63 68 65 0d 0a    43 61 63 68 65 2d 43 6f    -cache..Cache-Co
      6e 74 72 6f 6c 3a 20 6e    6f 2d 63 61 63 68 65 0d    ntrol: no-cache.
      0a 0d 0a                                              ...

    #
    T 104.131.x.x:80 -> 105.210.y.y:49983 [A]
    #
    T 104.131.x.x:80 -> 105.210.y.y:49983 [AP]
      48 54 54 50 2f 31 2e 31    20 31 30 31 20 53 77 69    HTTP/1.1 101 Swi
      74 63 68 69 6e 67 20 50    72 6f 74 6f 63 6f 6c 73    tching Protocols
      0d 0a 53 65 72 76 65 72    3a 20 41 70 61 63 68 65    ..Server: Apache
      2d 43 6f 79 6f 74 65 2f    31 2e 31 0d 0a 55 70 67    -Coyote/1.1..Upg
      72 61 64 65 3a 20 77 65    62 73 6f 63 6b 65 74 0d    rade: websocket.
      0a 43 6f 6e 6e 65 63 74    69 6f 6e 3a 20 75 70 67    .Connection: upg
      72 61 64 65 0d 0a 53 65    63 2d 57 65 62 53 6f 63    rade..Sec-WebSoc
      6b 65 74 2d 41 63 63 65    70 74 3a 20 52 56 43 4b    ket-Accept: RVCK
      72 41 6c 7a 59 30 66 4b    38 38 61 4d 43 30 61 37    rAlzY0fK88aMC0a7
      6e 31 74 62 35 71 38 3d    0d 0a 44 61 74 65 3a 20    n1tb5q8=..Date: 
      57 65 64 2c 20 32 34 20    44 65 63 20 32 30 31 34    Wed, 24 Dec 2014
      20 31 34 3a 33 31 3a 33    39 20 47 4d 54 0d 0a 0d     14:31:39 GMT...
      0a                                                    .

    #
    T 104.131.x.x:80 -> 105.210.y.y:49975 [AF]
    #
    T 105.210.y.y:49983 -> 104.131.x.x:80 [A]
      00 00 00 00 00 00                                     ......

    #
    T 105.210.y.y:49983 -> 104.131.x.x:80 [AP]
      82 9c a1 86 a8 97 a9 86    bb dd a0 b7 bc 84 eb 80    ................
      dc f2 d2 f2 99 a2 b5 95    e2 90 d5 e3 db e3 90 b4    ................
      9b 83                                                 ..

    #
    T 104.131.x.x:80 -> 105.210.y.y:49983 [AP]
      82 09                                                 ..

    #
    T 104.131.x.x:80 -> 105.210.y.y:49983 [AP]
      08 00 13 4a 03 32 37 30    14                         ...J.270.

    #
    T 105.210.y.y:49975 -> 104.131.x.x:80 [AFP]
      88 8a bc 23 03 08 bf ca    50 60 c9 57 67 67 cb 4d    ...#....P.Wgg.M
    #
    T 104.131.x.x:80 -> 105.210.y.y:49975 [A]
    #
    T 105.210.y.y:49983 -> 104.131.x.x:80 [A]
      00 00 00 00 00 00                                     ......

    #
    T 104.131.x.x:80 -> 105.210.y.y:49975 [AF]
    #
    T 105.210.y.y:49975 -> 104.131.x.x:80 [AFP]
      88 8a bc 23 03 08 bf ca    50 60 c9 57 67 67 cb 4d    ...#....P.Wgg.M
    #
    T 104.131.x.x:80 -> 105.210.y.y:49975 [A]
    #
    T 105.210.y.y:49983 -> 104.131.x.x:80 [AP]
      88 8a ad d9 9f c4 ae 30    cc ac d8 ad fb ab da b7    .......0........
    #
    T 105.210.y.y:49983 -> 104.131.x.x:80 [AF]
      00 00 00 00 00 00                                     ......

    #
    T 104.131.x.x:80 -> 105.210.y.y:49983 [AF]
    #
    T 105.210.y.y:49983 -> 104.131.x.x:80 [AFP]
      88 8a ad d9 9f c4 ae 30    cc ac d8 ad fb ab da b7    .......0........
    #
    T 104.131.x.x:80 -> 105.210.y.y:49983 [A]
    #
    T 105.210.y.y:49983 -> 104.131.x.x:80 [AFP]
      88 8a ad d9 9f c4 ae 30    cc ac d8 ad fb ab da b7    .......0........
    #
    T 104.131.x.x:80 -> 105.210.y.y:49983 [A]
    #
    T 104.131.x.x:80 -> 105.210.y.y:49983 [AF]
    #
    T 105.210.y.y:49983 -> 104.131.x.x:80 [AFP]
      88 8a ad d9 9f c4 ae 30    cc ac d8 ad fb ab da b7    .......0........
    #
    T 104.131.x.x:80 -> 105.210.y.y:49983 [A]
    #
    T 104.131.x.x:80 -> 105.210.y.y:49983 [AF]
    #
    T 105.210.y.y:49991 -> 104.131.x.x:80 [S]
    #
    T 104.131.x.x:80 -> 105.210.y.y:49991 [AS]
    #
    T 104.131.x.x:80 -> 105.210.y.y:49975 [AF]
    #
    T 105.210.y.y:49991 -> 104.131.x.x:80 [A]
      00 00 00 00 00 00                                     ......

    #
    T 105.210.y.y:49991 -> 104.131.x.x:80 [AP]
      47 45 54 20 2f 74 72 61    6e 73 6c 61 74 6f 72 2d    GET /trandomain-
      73 72 76 2f 77 73 20 48    54 54 50 2f 31 2e 31 0d    srv/ws HTTP/1.1.
      0a 48 6f 73 74 3a 20 77    73 2e 73 6c 61 74 6f 72    .Host: ws.domain
      2e 69 6f 0d 0a 55 70 67    72 61 64 65 3a 20 77 65    .io..Upgrade: we
      62 73 6f 63 6b 65 74 0d    0a 43 6f 6e 6e 65 63 74    bsocket..Connect
      69 6f 6e 3a 20 55 70 67    72 61 64 65 0d 0a 53 65    ion: Upgrade..Se
      63 2d 57 65 62 53 6f 63    6b 65 74 2d 4b 65 79 3a    c-WebSocket-Key:
      20 62 45 54 54 44 72 77    54 75 69 64 4f 67 4a 4a     bETTDrwTuidOgJJ
      68 73 56 7a 31 4c 41 3d    3d 0d 0a 53 65 63 2d 57    hsVz1LA==..Sec-W
      65 62 53 6f 63 6b 65 74    2d 56 65 72 73 69 6f 6e    ebSocket-Version
      3a 20 31 33 0d 0a 50 72    61 67 6d 61 3a 20 6e 6f    : 13..Pragma: no
      2d 63 61 63 68 65 0d 0a    43 61 63 68 65 2d 43 6f    -cache..Cache-Co
      6e 74 72 6f 6c 3a 20 6e    6f 2d 63 61 63 68 65 0d    ntrol: no-cache.
      0a 0d 0a                                              ...

    #
    T 104.131.x.x:80 -> 105.210.y.y:49991 [A]
    #
    T 104.131.x.x:80 -> 105.210.y.y:49991 [AP]
      88 0a 03 e9 53 68 75 74    64 6f 77 6e                ....Shutdown

    #
    T 104.131.x.x:80 -> 105.210.y.y:49991 [AP]
      3c 21 44 4f 43 54 59 50    45 20 48 54 4d 4c 20 50    ..
      3c 74 69 74 6c 65 3e 35    30 30 20 49 6e 74 65 72    500 Inter
      6e 61 6c 20 53 65 72 76    65 72 20 45 72 72 6f 72    nal Server Error
      3c 2f 74 69 74 6c 65 3e    0a 3c 2f 68 65 61 64 3e    .
      3c 62 6f 64 79 3e 0a 3c    68 31 3e 49 6e 74 65 72    .
Inter
      6e 61 6c 20 53 65 72 76    65 72 20 45 72 72 6f 72    nal Server Error
      3c 2f 68 31 3e 0a 3c 70    3e 54 68 65 20 73 65 72

.
The ser
      76 65 72 20 65 6e 63 6f    75 6e 74 65 72 65 64 20    ver encountered 
      61 6e 20 69 6e 74 65 72    6e 61 6c 20 65 72 72 6f    an internal erro
      72 20 6f 72 0a 6d 69 73    63 6f 6e 66 69 67 75 72    r or.misconfigur
      61 74 69 6f 6e 20 61 6e    64 20 77 61 73 20 75 6e    ation and was un
      61 62 6c 65 20 74 6f 20    63 6f 6d 70 6c 65 74 65    able to complete
      0a 79 6f 75 72 20 72 65    71 75 65 73 74 2e 3c 2f    .your request..`

Please con
      74 61 63 74 20 74 68 65    20 73 65 72 76 65 72 20    tact the server 
      61 64 6d 69 6e 69 73 74    72 61 74 6f 72 20 61 74    administrator at
      20 0a 20 77 65 62 6d 61    73 74 65 72 40 6c 6f 63     . webmaster@loc
      61 6c 68 6f 73 74 20 74    6f 20 69 6e 66 6f 72 6d    alhost to inform
      20 74 68 65 6d 20 6f 66    20 74 68 65 20 74 69 6d     them of the tim
      65 20 74 68 69 73 20 65    72 72 6f 72 20 6f 63 63    e this error occ
      75 72 72 65 64 2c 0a 20    61 6e 64 20 74 68 65 20    urred,. and the 
      61 63 74 69 6f 6e 73 20    79 6f 75 20 70 65 72 66    actions you perf
      6f 72 6d 65 64 20 6a 75    73 74 20 62 65 66 6f 72    ormed just befor
      65 20 74 68 69 73 20 65    72 72 6f 72 2e 3c 2f 70    e this error..

More inform
      61 74 69 6f 6e 20 61 62    6f 75 74 20 74 68 69 73    ation about this
      20 65 72 72 6f 72 20 6d    61 79 20 62 65 20 61 76     error may be av
      61 69 6c 61 62 6c 65 0a    69 6e 20 74 68 65 20 73    ailable.in the s
      65 72 76 65 72 20 65 72    72 6f 72 20 6c 6f 67 2e    erver error log.
      3c 2f 70 3e 0a 3c 68 72    3e 0a 3c 61 64 64 72 65

.
.Apache/2.4.7 
      28 55 62 75 6e 74 75 29    20 53 65 72 76 65 72 20    (Ubuntu) Server 
      61 74 20 77 73 2e 73 6c    61 74 6f 72 2e 69 6f 20    at ws.domain.io 
      50 6f 72 74 20 38 30 3c    2f 61 64 64 72 65 73 73    Port 80.
      0a                                                    .
    #
    T 104.131.x.x:80 -> 105.210.y.y:49991 [AF]
    #
    T 105.210.y.y:49991 -> 104.131.x.x:80 [A]
      00 00 00 00 00 00                                     ......
    #
    T 105.210.y.y:49991 -> 104.131.x.x:80 [A]
      00 00 00 00 00 00                                     ......
    #
    T 105.210.y.y:49983 -> 104.131.x.x:80 [AFP]
      88 8a ad d9 9f c4 ae 30    cc ac d8 ad fb ab da b7    .......0........
    #
    T 104.131.x.x:80 -> 105.210.y.y:49983 [A]
    #
    T 104.131.x.x:80 -> 105.210.y.y:49983 [AF]
    #
    T 105.210.y.y:49975 -> 104.131.x.x:80 [AR]
      00 00 00 00 00 00                                     ......
    #
    T 104.131.x.x:80 -> 105.210.y.y:49983 [AF]
    #
    T 105.210.y.y:49983 -> 104.131.x.x:80 [AFP]
      88 8a ad d9 9f c4 ae 30    cc ac d8 ad fb ab da b7    .......0........
    #
    T 104.131.x.x:80 -> 105.210.y.y:49983 [A]
    #
    T 105.210.y.y:49991 -> 104.131.x.x:80 [AF]
      00 00 00 00 00 00                                     ......
    #
    T 104.131.x.x:80 -> 105.210.y.y:49991 [A]
    #
    T 105.210.y.y:49991 -> 104.131.x.x:80 [AF]
      00 00 00 00 00 00                                     ......
    #
    T 104.131.x.x:80 -> 105.210.y.y:49991 [A]
    #
    T 105.210.y.y:49991 -> 104.131.x.x:80 [AF]
      00 00 00 00 00 00                                     ......
    #
    T 104.131.x.x:80 -> 105.210.y.y:49991 [A]
    #
    T 105.210.y.y:49991 -> 104.131.x.x:80 [AF]
      00 00 00 00 00 00                                     ......
    #
    T 104.131.x.x:80 -> 105.210.y.y:49991 [A]
    #
    T 104.131.x.x:80 -> 105.210.y.y:49983 [AF]
    #
    T 105.210.y.y:49991 -> 104.131.x.x:80 [AF]
      00 00 00 00 00 00                                     ......
    #
    T 104.131.x.x:80 -> 105.210.y.y:49991 [A]
    #
    T 105.210.y.y:49983 -> 104.131.x.x:80 [AR]
      00 00 00 00 00 00                                     ......
    #
    T 105.210.y.y:49991 -> 104.131.x.x:80 [AF]
      00 00 00 00 00 00                                     ......
    #
    T 104.131.x.x:80 -> 105.210.y.y:49991 [A]
    exit
    83 received, 0 dropped

The ngrep output on port 8080 (between apache and tomcat)

`interface: lo (127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0)
filter: (ip or ip6) and ( port 8080 )
#
T 127.0.0.1:57952 -> 127.0.0.1:8080 [AP]
  47 45 54 20 2f 74 72 61    6e 73 6c 61 74 6f 72 2d    GET /translator-
  73 72 76 2f 77 73 20 48    54 54 50 2f 31 2e 31 0d    srv/ws HTTP/1.1.
  0a 48 6f 73 74 3a 20 6c    6f 63 61 6c 68 6f 73 74    .Host: localhost
  3a 38 30 38 30 0d 0a 53    65 63 2d 57 65 62 53 6f    :8080..Sec-WebSo
  63 6b 65 74 2d 4b 65 79    3a 20 64 36 57 73 6c 6b    cket-Key: d6Wslk
  56 48 77 79 4d 47 77 62    5a 4f 6c 71 56 53 2b 51    VHwyMGwbZOlqVS+Q
  3d 3d 0d 0a 53 65 63 2d    57 65 62 53 6f 63 6b 65    ==..Sec-WebSocke
  74 2d 56 65 72 73 69 6f    6e 3a 20 31 33 0d 0a 50    t-Version: 13..P
  72 61 67 6d 61 3a 20 6e    6f 2d 63 61 63 68 65 0d    ragma: no-cache.
  0a 43 61 63 68 65 2d 43    6f 6e 74 72 6f 6c 3a 20    .Cache-Control: 
  6e 6f 2d 63 61 63 68 65    0d 0a 58 2d 46 6f 72 77    no-cache..X-Forw
  61 72 64 65 64 2d 46 6f    72 3a 20 31 30 35 2e 32    arded-For: 105.2
  31 30 2e 33 38 2e 31 34    39 0d 0a 58 2d 46 6f 72    10.38.149..X-For
  77 61 72 64 65 64 2d 48    6f 73 74 3a 20 77 73 2e    warded-Host: ws.
  73 6c 61 74 6f 72 2e 69    6f 0d 0a 58 2d 46 6f 72    slator.io..X-For
  77 61 72 64 65 64 2d 53    65 72 76 65 72 3a 20 77    warded-Server: w
  73 2e 73 6c 61 74 6f 72    2e 69 6f 0d 0a 55 70 67    s.slator.io..Upg
  72 61 64 65 3a 20 57 65    62 53 6f 63 6b 65 74 0d    rade: WebSocket.
  0a 43 6f 6e 6e 65 63 74    69 6f 6e 3a 20 55 70 67    .Connection: Upg
  72 61 64 65 0d 0a 0d 0a                               rade....

#
T 127.0.0.1:8080 -> 127.0.0.1:57952 [R]`

Lastly for completeness the jetty error

```
    org.eclipse.jetty.util.Utf8Appendable$NotUtf8Exception: Not valid UTF8! byte 88 in state 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to compile the latest version of apache on my server and that seemed to solve the issue.

I created this question and answer to document that process:

https://serverfault.com/questions/655722/how-do-i-compile-the-latest-apache2-on-ubuntu-using-the-original-layout-configu